# ReactJS set onchange on component render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a component called `DropDown`:

```
export default class DropDown extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <select multiple={this.props.multiple} onChange={this.props.onchange} id={this.props.id} className={this.props.class}>
                {this.props.children}
            </select>
        )
    }
}
```

And want to use this in another component:

```
getSelected = (e) => {
console.log(e);
};
render(){
    return(
        <DropDown id="Test" multiple onChange="this.getSelected()" class="ui fluid dropdown search" ref="Item">
            {Data.map((v,i) => {
                return (
                    <option key={i} value={v.id}>{v.name}</option>
                )
            })}
        </DropDown>
}
}
```

As you see, I want to have a dynamic DropDown, and want to pass id, class, multiple, even onchange function name, class and id working good but multiple and onchange function not working, how can I pass multiple and a handle function name to on change event in component?

Comment: Hi friend! See my solution below and let me know if that helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it! Make sure that the props that you passed from the Parent component match exactly with what you're using in the component.

For example, in your Dropdown component you use `onChange={this.props.onchange}` but you actually named the prop  `<DropDown onChange="this.getSelected()">`. There's a typo there. It should be `onChange={this.props.onChange}`

Additionally, when passing a function as prop, you do not need to initiate it, just pass a reference to it like `<DropDown onChange={this.getSelected}>`

See sandbox and working code: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-raman-jbdph

## App.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import DropDown from "./DropDown";

import "./styles.css";

const data = [{ id: 1, name: "Fred" }, { id: 2, name: "Burger" }];

class App extends React.Component {
  getSelected = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };

  dropdownRef = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.dropdownRef.current) {
      console.log(this.dropdownRef.current);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <DropDown
        onChange={this.getSelected}
        multiple
        reference={this.dropdownRef}
      >
        {data.map((item, index) => {
          return <option value={item.id}>{item.name}</option>;
        })}
      </DropDown>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

### DropDown.js

```
import React from "react";

class DropDown extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <select
        ref={this.props.reference}
        multiple={this.props.multiple}
        onChange={this.props.onChange}
        id={this.props.id}
        className={this.props.class}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </select>
    );
  }
}

export default DropDown;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it work perfectly, just another small question, what about ref? how can I do this with ref? I tested but not working in this way

Comment: @tourtravel Let me see if I can get the ref to work :)

Comment: @tourtravel see my updated answer and the sandbox as well. You first need to create a `ref object` by using `React.createRef()`, then you can pass it as a prop to the `DropDown`. I named the prop `reference`. Then inside the `DropDown` component, assign that `ref` to a piece of the markup, like the `select` tag.

Answer (score 1):

For multiple, if you want a Boolean value, use `multiple={true}` instead of just multiple with no value, that works if you're checking for defined vs undefined but not ideal in this case.

For onChange, you need to pass `onChange={this.getSelected}` this passes the function the way you want. Note that the event object will automatically be passed to getSelected.

The next paragraph is not for your use case but is good to know...

If you wanted to pass a specific parameter to getSelected you would do `onChange={() => {this.getSelected("hello");}` but you'd have to add a constructor to the class and add the line `this.getSelected = this.getSelected.bind(this);` so that the function knows that 'this' refers to the class and not the click event.